# Using onchange to send get requests to API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a registration form where the user adds their `postcode` and by sending a `GET` request to an API, I receive and show the `address` in the fields below.

My problem is that I am currently using `onchange: "getAddress(this.value)"` in the form_tag itself however I would like to implement it using a jQuery event handler. This is how my code within the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page looks like:

```
var getAddress = function(postcode) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= get_address_url %>',
        dataType: 'script',
        type: "GET",
        data: { postcode: postcode }
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    dooo();
    $(this).on("change", "input", dooo);
    var p = $("input#jobseeker_postcode");
    $(this).on("change", "input#jobseeker_postcode", getAddress(p.val()));
});
```

The `doo()` function is declared in my .js files and the event handler managing it works like a charm. However I don't manage to get the postcode thing(second event handler in the code) to run. What I have figured out is that the value of the field is not properly retreived, as no matter what I fill in, I get a `failed response` from the API => the `value` that I am passing is `""`.

FYI the `doo()` function implements a `jQuery UI` progress bar which loads based on how many fields are filled in.

Comment: `on` needs a function. You should change `getAddress` so that it returns a function.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the change event handler to a function. Since you need to pass a parameter into the handler function, it should be defined within a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

This should work:

```
var getAddress = function(postcode) {
    return function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '<%= get_address_url %>',
        dataType: 'script',
        type: "GET",
        data: { postcode: postcode }
      });
    };
};
```

Comment: That seems to solve the triggering problem. It now triggers properly, but it still returns a value that is `""`, thus tells me postcode doesn't exist.